# Multi master replication

Tags: java, mysql

How does Java application connect to multi master replicated MySQL Database?

I am using `com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationDriver`

but this is giving exception as:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

Comment: Please read this, I hope it helps:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983248/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexception-communications-link-fai

Comment: My JDBC URL is String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:mysql:replication://address=(host=localhost)(port=3308)(type=master),"
       + "address=(host=localhost)(port=3306)(type=master)";

Comment: This is having multi paster only...on a single machine (localhost)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you read the thread I've sent you in the comments of your question? Didn't help? Try this tutorial on creating a step-by-step MySQL+JDBC tutorial

[Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/java-connectivity-with-mysql/2840358#2840358)

I hope it helps